# Post to timeline like Candy Crush Saga

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I want to post to user time-line with their current activity with photo uploaded by them.

For example:

I voted 'xyz movie'.

..image1.. ..image2.. ..image3..

**Question :** Mutiple photos possible? If yes, Is there limit of photos.I need to show 3-5 photos

Similar to Candy crush saga game post:
(just for reference,not exactly like this. For curiosity I wanted to know whether this is two posts?)

[image]

Which api can we use for this?

Is this possible with FB.ui feed api?

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    to:'the Facebook ID of the person you wanna send',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://emplido.com',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called rich stories, you can create them with open graph, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share) you can see what are the options available.

This is no easy deal, since you have a lot of options, so you really need to read the open graph docs to find which action fits best. In the docs you have a complete "how to", including how to post an action on a users wall with **graph api** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/

Remember that you have to two types of actions, **common** (docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/)) and **custom** (docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#actiontypes))

I know that documentation isn't the best answer or the one you wanted to, but in this case it's really necessary, as I said before, you have too many options, that allows you to create the best user experience for your app.

Quoting the docs here's a little example on how to create a story with open graph

To publish an action, make an HTTP POST to the following Graph API endpoint:

```
 /{user-id}/{action-type}
```

> *This call should be signed with a user* **access token** *with*
>   **publish_actions** *permission or with an* **app access token** *for a user who was previously logged in.*

For common actions, the {action-type} is the name of the action, such as og.likes:

```
/{user-id}/og.likes
```

For custom actions, it is a composite of the app namespace and the custom action type:

```
/{user-id}/{namespace}:{action-type-name}
```

> *The namespace is unique to your app, and is set in your app's dashboard on the Basic tab.*

This example is the simplest one.

Comment: thanks.Sorry for late reply.I wanted to try this.Currently displaying activity in "recent activity" bar. But I wanted to find out how it looks in others news-feed? and also wanted to know how to give link to movie name which should open movie detail page in facebook app. Currently it is taking outside the facebook

Comment: {"title":"cool","message":"SDfsdf","fb:explicitly_shared":true,"url":"https://example.com/app_dev.php/root/","description":"cool place","image":[{'url':"http://personal.psu.edu/tao5048/JPG.jpg","user_generated":true},{'url':"http://personal.psu.edu/tao5048/JPG.jpg","user_generated":true}]} is my post body

Comment: could you explain yourself better?

Comment: You want me to explain in detail ?

Comment: yeah what do you mean with this "and also wanted to know how to give link to movie name which should open movie detail page in facebook app"

Comment: In recent activity we'll get activity like "I voted xyz movie as best movie".In this example xyz is movie name which will be click-able.Currently it is taking to page outside facebook (To defined URL). But I want open page as iframe page within my app

Comment: that's a different question, what's the type of your app? canvas, page tab, website, ios, android,...?

Comment: In that case to redirect a user to a page tab you just need to do this `https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_ID or PAGE_NAMESPACE/?sk=app_APP_ID&app_data={"movie":"movie_id"}` the app_data will be available on the signed_request

Comment: I posted as new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903882/facebook-story-display-in-newsfeed