# Facebook story mutiple photos display in newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-stream-story

I'm working on creating facebook stories for my facebook page app.My requirement is to display activity "I voted for this movie " with images as shown in image [image]

I tried posting through Graph api explorer:

```
 {"title":"cool","fb:explicitly_shared":true,"url":"http://www.facebook.com/name/app_id","description":"cool place",
"image":[{'url':"http://personal.psu.edu/tao5048/JPG.jpg","user_generated":true},{'url':"http://personal.psu.edu/tao5048/JPG.jpg","user_generated":true}]}
```

In my activity log :
[image]
But in friends news feed I'm getting like :

[image]

there is nothing like "I voted...." in post.Is anything I'm doing wrong?.

**Note:** apps is not in sandbox mode. Story is not submitted for approval(Only for testing).

**Edit**

If I remove `"user_generated":true` ill get single image(even 2 images uploaded) with proper post.

[image]

Comment: Have you configured your app actions? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#actiontypes

Comment: Ya.It is coming in activity log.I added image in my question

Comment: I think I got the problem. Edited above post.But still waiting for solution